# Elasticsearch java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch index were working from past year and suddenly I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/var/data/lib/elasticsearch)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:316)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:256)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:183)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:45)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/data/lib
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:308)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:746)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:337)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
        ... 7 more
```

I haven't changed any file permissions. They were working fine till now.

cd /var/data/lib/elasticsearch

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Nov 19  2020 elasticsearch
```

Did this happen to anyone? I stopped my Elasticsearch, and now I am not able to start it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you happen to figure this out?

Comment: @user304584  Yes. The full permission of the folder should be elasticsearch:elasticsearch not only the inside folder